# Not able to get value from Json key

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to get an object from Mongoose but when I get it and try to access the Json object by key to get the value i get undefined.

```
User.find({name: 'auth'},function (err,obj) {

    var authCode = JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(authCode);
    var parse = JSON.parse(authCode);
    console.log(parse);
    console.log(parse.code);
});
```

I get the following output:

```
[{"_id":"5a43b491734d1d45eaf2d00d","name":"auth","code":"nCAxOSrUMqxtxd8T"}]
[ { _id: '5a43b491734d1d45eaf2d00d',
    name: 'auth',
    code: 'nCAxOSrUMqxtxd8T' } ]
undefined
```

I have even tried `console.log(parse['code'])`and i still get `undefined`. Can someone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse` variable above is not a dictionary itself, but an array containing a dictionary. What you should do to access the code field would be first access the dictionary and then get the code field like;

```
parse[0].code
```

or

```
parse[0]['code']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not parse or stringify the returned JSON object. You can use the JSON object as it is. 
**Try below approach**

```
User.find({name: 'auth'},function (err,obj) {
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(obj.code);// this will probably be undefined as find method returns array of objects ( correct me if iam wrong)

    user.forEach(function(obj,index){
                console.log("index: "+index);
                console.log("obj: "+obj.code);
             });
});
```

**Using promises is a good way**

```
User.find({name: 'auth'})
        .then((user)=>{
             console.log("find success");
             console.log(user);
             console.log(user.code); // would return undefined as User.find will return array of objects

             user.forEach(function(obj,index){
                console.log("index: "+index);
                console.log("obj: "+obj.code);
             });
        })
        .catch(()=> {
            console.log("find failed");
        });
```